# How to create custom bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to create custom bottom navigation bar in flutter with different custom shape.
how to create custom rounded container with gradient background for bottom navigation bar buttons.
How to make simple ease-in animation on it.

[image: like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `animated_bottom_navigation_bar` package to achieve your design.

Here is the package link: [animated_bottom_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar)

Here is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.black,
          child: const Icon(Icons.music_note_outlined),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
        icons: const [Icons.abc, Icons.baby_changing_station],
        activeIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
        gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
        notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.softEdge,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => _bottomNavIndex = index),
        // other params
      ),
    );
  }
```

Expected output:
[image: Bottom tab]

Answer (score 1):

You can go really custom with containers. My code is not for navigation, but here is an example of a custom nav bar.

```
class mainBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const mainBody({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const Drawer(
        child: sideMenu(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:
            Text('Dice Roller (${context.watch<diceList>().totalDiceNumber})'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      body: const diceZone(),
      bottomNavigationBar: const bottom_navBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

my container

```
class bottom_navBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const bottom_navBar({super.key});
  @override
  State<bottom_navBar> createState() => _bottom_navBarState();
}

class _bottom_navBarState extends State<bottom_navBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25, top: 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  //artır
                  context.read<diceList>().addDice(randomNumber());
                  //ChangeNotifier(); buna gerek yokmuş baya gereksiz bir parça
                });
              },
              onLongPress: () {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  context.read<diceList>().addDice(randomNumber());
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey.shade900),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 54,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  //reroll
                  HapticFeedback.vibrate();
                  context.read<diceList>().reRollDice();
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade900),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Roll ${context.watch<diceList>().diceses.length} Dice',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.fade),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.refresh,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 54,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  //azalt
                  int i = context.read<diceList>().diceses.length;
                  if (i > 1) {
                    i--;
                    context.read<diceList>().removeDice(0);
                  }
                });
              },
              onLongPress: () {
                for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
                  int i = context.read<diceList>().diceses.length;
                  if (i > 1) {
                    context.read<diceList>().removeDice(0);
                  }
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey.shade900),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.remove,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 54,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beq1h.png)